# How can I get a panel allways centered in xfce4?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel, xfce-panel

I installed `xfce4` on two completely fresh Ubuntu-Server installs within virtual machines on VMware Workstation Player.

```
sudo apt install xfce4 open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

The first time I started `startx` I got a prompt on both machines whether to start with a default panel setup or an empty one.

Accidentely on one of them I choose `start with empty panel` so I had to rebuild it by myself using the other server as template.

Anyway I still have trouble to get the bottom panel (`Panel 2` if choosing the default start option) centered like on the first server.

This is how the panel looks like with the default option 
(after resizing VMware Workstation Player):
[image: xfce4 with centered bottom panel]

This is how the manually rebuild panel looks like 
(after resizing VMWare Workstation Player):
[image]

In the panel options I have not found any option/setting related to the positioning of the panels. So:

**How can I get the bottom panel always be centered on the screen like in the default setup?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the panel, in the context-menu choose `Panel > Panel Preferences`

In the now open `Panel Preferences`-window uncheck the box `Lock panel`. The panel is unlocked now and two handles are added to it. Left-click on one of the handles and move the panel to the center (keep left mouse button pressed). Move slowly, you should feel the panel snapping to center position if you are near to the center. Release the mouse button when the panel is in the desired position.

Leave the panel there and lock the panel (check the box `Lock panel` in the `Panel Preferences`-window). The panel-handles disappear and the panel is locked at center position, you can close the `Panel Preferences`-window now .

Comment: Thanks, but I did exactly those steps before resizing the Player. I also thought this should do it since I felt the "snapping". After the snapp to the center I re-enabled `Lock panel` but it stays at this position as in my pictures.

Comment: @derHugo Strange, I think this is the way it should work, I guess it's an issue with your VMWare Workstation Player. No idea for that, sorry...

Comment: yeah .. I just tried it two times again and the second time suddenly worked ^^ maybe releasing the mouse button after the snapp I got it off again a millimeter? Might be an issue to get it well done in a VM but now it does what it should so thanks anyway ;)